# Python 3.6 pandas import error from 'UserDict.py'

Tags: python, pandas, import, python-3.6

I'm running Python 3.6.4, and am getting an import error from pandas. I'm installing it with 'pip install pandas' (which installs version 0.22). Installing it seems to go fine, but when I try to import it, an error gets thrown:

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytz\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
     from pytz.lazy import LazyDict, LazyList, LazySet
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytz\lazy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from UserDict import DictMixin
  File "C:\Python36\lib\UserDict.py", line 167
    raise TypeError, "pop expected at most 2 arguments, got "\
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!!

Edit:
Stephen pointed out that the root problem is pytz failing to import. Importing anything form pytz throws the same error. I've found one reference to the same error (http://www.smashcompany.com/technology/weird-that-under-python-3-4-runtime-you-can-import-from-2-7), which suggested an old path variable was the problem. I don't see any outdated python variables in my PATH, however.

Comment: It is failing when importing pytz.  You might try `pip3 install -U pytz`

Comment: When I try 'pip3 install -U pytz' it gives me:                                                       
    Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'                                                                          When I try just 'pip install -U pytz' it says 'requirement already up to date'

Comment: The above fatal error was because I had renamed the folder. I changed it back and pip3 works fine again, but just returns 'requirement met' for pytz

Comment: Can you import pytz in your program?  Or maybe `from pytz.lazy import LazyDict, LazyList, LazySet`?

Comment: Those all throw the same original error.

Comment: So there is the root of your issue.  Wish I could help further. You might try uninstalling/reinstalling `pytz`. Good luck.

Comment: Reinstalling pytz didn't help, but thanks for helping me narrow down the root cause!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use a virtual environment, `pip` usually corresponds to Python 2.x. The convention is to use `pip3` to refer to the pip binary for Python 3.x. Since you are using 3.6.4, `pip` may be installing pandas for the wrong version of Python. You can confirm if it's using the correct one with

```
pip --version
```

If it says that it's using an interpreter other than the one you are using to run your code, try using

```
pip3 install pandas
```

instead.

Comment: returns: pip 9.0.1 from C:\Python36\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out what caused the problem, but I was able to fix this by manually deleting all of the python files and directories still left behind after uninstalling python (not sure if it is normal that files were left at all) and then doing a completely fresh install.

There were no import problems after a 100% fresh install. Something must have gotten messed up, and running the default 'repair' or 'uninstall' and 'install' through the python installer (of multiple versions) wasn't correcting it.